# Count how many cell string values in a column are found in an table-like database

Tags: google-sheets-formula

### Spreadsheet's structure:

1. A phrases bank in range `B4:J24` in tab **`phrases bank`** (Row 4 is for headers). Let's call it *`bank range`*.
2. A list of phrases in range `J4:J` in tab **`phrases`**. (Row 4 is for headers). Let's call it *`phases range`*.

### Goal:

Check how many phrases in *`phases range`* are found in *`bank range`*.

### Failed attempt:

```
=DCOUNTA(phrases!J4:J,1,B4:J24)
```

* found in **`phrases bank`** tab.

It returns all phrases in *`phases range`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For total Found

```
=arrayformula(sum(COUNTIF(B5:J24,phrases!J4:J)))
```

For Each Found

```
=arrayformula(COUNTIF(B5:J24,phrases!J4:J))
```

Comment: Thank you! Just out of curiosity - do you know why the `=DCOUNTA()` did not work?